# Do not show error messages when validate a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When the form is validated, this must show the error message. However it´s not showing.

My view looks like this:

```
<% form_for :invite, :url => profile_invites_path do |f| -%>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<p><label for="email_to"><%= t 'invites.new.labels.mail'%></label><br/>
<%= f.text_field :email_to %></p>

<p><label for="role_id"><%= t 'invites.new.labels.role'%></label><br/>
<%= collection_select(:invite, :type, Role.players , :name, :printable_name) %></p>

<p><label for="message"><%= t 'invites.new.labels.message'%></label><br/>
<%= f.text_area :message %></p>

<p><%= submit_tag "#{ t 'application.send'}" %></p>
<% end -%>
```

My model looks like this

```
class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = "invite_type"

  RE_EMAIL_NAME   = '[\w\.%\+\-]+'                          # what you actually see in practice
  #RE_EMAIL_NAME   = '0-9A-Z!#\$%\&\'\*\+_/=\?^\-`\{|\}~\.' # technically allowed by RFC-2822
  RE_DOMAIN_HEAD  = '(?:[A-Z0-9\-]+\.)+'
  RE_DOMAIN_TLD   = '(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)'
  RE_EMAIL_OK     = /\A#{RE_EMAIL_NAME}@#{RE_DOMAIN_HEAD}#{RE_DOMAIN_TLD}\z/i
  MSG_EMAIL_BAD   = "should look like an email address."

  # Validates
  validate :validate_presence_mail, :message => :"email.blank"
  validates_format_of :email_to, :on => :update, :with => RE_EMAIL_OK, :message => MSG_EMAIL_BAD
  validates_uniqueness_of :email_to, :on => :update, :scope => :profile_id, :message => :"email_to.taken"
  validates_presence_of :token
  validates_uniqueness_of :token
  validates_length_of :message, :minimum => 5

  def validate_presence_mail
    presence_of(self.email_to, "email.to")
  end

  def presence_of(attrib, field)
    if attrib.blank?
      error_path = I18n.t "activerecord.errors.full_messages.#{field}.blank"
      self.errors.add_to_base("#{error_path}")
    end
  end
end
```

Although error messages syntax is specified in the view and errors are added in the model, they are not being shown.

---

This is the form in the view

```
<% content_for :header do -%>
<% t 'invites.new.title'%> <%= configatron.site_name %>
<% end -%>

<% content_for :sidebar do -%>

<p>
    <% t 'invites.new.indication'%>
</p>
<% end -%>



<% form_for @invite, :url => profile_invites_path do |f| -%>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<p><label for="email_to"><%= t 'invites.new.labels.mail'%></label><br/>
<%= f.text_field :email_to %></p>

<p><label for="role_id"><%= t 'invites.new.labels.role'%></label><br/>
<%= collection_select(:invite, :type, Role.players , :name, :printable_name) %></p>

<p><label for="message"><%= t 'invites.new.labels.message'%></label><br/>
<%= f.text_area :message %></p>

<p><%= submit_tag "#{ t 'application.send'}" %></p>
<% end -%>

<%= link_to "#{ t 'application.back'}", profile_invites_path %>
```

This is the new controller

```
def new
    @invite = Invite.new
  end

  def index
    @profile = current_user.profile
    @ps_invites = Invite.of_profile(@profile.id).for_powerful_supplier.available.count
    @ubc_invites = Invite.of_profile(@profile.id).for_business_contact.available.count

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @invites }
    end
  end

  def create
    @invite = Invite.of_type(params[:invite][:type]).of_profile(current_user.profile.id).available.first

    unless @invite.nil?
      @invite.status = 'pending'
      @invite.message = params[:invite][:message]
      @invite.email_to = params[:invite][:email_to]
      if @invite.save
        InviteMailer.deliver_send_invite(@invite)
        flash.now[:notice] = t 'invites.messages.sent'
        redirect_to(profile_invites_url)
      else
        flash.now[:error] =  t "invites.messages.not_sent"
        render :controller => 'invites' ,:action => "new"
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = t("invites.messages.without_invite", :profile_type => params[:invite][:type])
      render :controller => 'invites' ,:action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with this:

```
<% form_for @invite, :url => profile_invites_path do |f| -%>
```

Comment: No, I have other forms with symbol and these take the errors.

Comment: Excuse me, The other comment is bad. The error was mine. your solution is correct

Comment: Excuse me. now i have other problem. the validation show but when i try submit the form again appear the next error:                                                       Unknown action

No action responded to 2. Actions: access_denied, answer_message, check_roles, connections, destroy_picture, disconnect, edit, network, new, received_messages, role_requirements, role_requirements=, s, save_picture, sent_messages, show, submit_pending_requests, switch_network_view, update, vote_negatively, and vote_positively

Comment: Sounds like your form route is incorrect. I suspect you're no longer providing a url to the path and the form_for helper is trying to guess it. Can you post your current form_for code in your question. Also, running rake routes from console will show you all the routes you have defined.